# want to make underline invisible when @Html.ActionLink() in MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using "@Html.ActionLink()" and used "text-decoration:none" in it. But still the link is showing underline for it.

Can anybody suggest solution for it to remove the underline.

Thanks,
Yuoraj

Comment: How did you use `text-decoration:none`? You should be using css (including applying the style to `a:hover` and `a:focus`)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it inline like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(<your params>, new { style="text-decoration:none"})
```

but really you should be using a css file and a class:

```
@Html.ActionLink(<your params>, new { @class="myclass"})
```

where myclass looks like

```
a.myclass {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

UPDATE:

```
a.hprLnkmastercls {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And if you don't want it underlined on hover

```
a.hprLnkmastercls:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

In your .cshtml

```
@Html.ActionLink("Process", "Home" "WebsiteHome", new {}, new { @class = "hprLnkmastercls" })
```

will render as:

```
<a class="hprLnkmastercls" href="/WebsiteHome/Home">Process</a>
```

Comment: Hi,
I tried this way also but no luck.
Could you please suggest another way to do this?

Thanks,
Yuoraj

Comment: Post your rendered HTML - I want to see what the <a href=""... /> looks like

Comment: Hi,
Below is my CSS style  code,

a.hprLnkmastercls
{
text-decoration:none;
}

AND, below is my .cshtml code,
@Html.ActionLink("Process","WebsiteHome","Home",new {@class="hprLnkmastercls"})

This is not working.

Comment: I want to see the rendered code - when you run the website and the page loads, do "View Source" and show us what anchor tag is created. We should see <a href="WebsiteHome/Process" class="hprLnkmastercls">text</a>

Comment: Here is my generated source code,
<a class="hprLnkmastercls" href="/Home/MossWebFlowHome?Length=4" style="color: #0a94d6;">Home </a>

Comment: I've just put in the syntax that will work. The @class was being used as the route values object. My apologies.

Comment: Hi
Isn't @class is my css class. Could you please elaborate @class= ? should be like.

Comment: Is my UPDATE above not clear? What does it render if you use that code?
Make sure your CSS file is being loaded (F12 -> Network tab)

Comment: Hi
css file is getting loaded properly, but still it is showing underline for that

Comment: Right-click on the link and click Inspect Element. On the right-hand side you will see all classes and styles being applied to that link. Does hprLnkmastercls appear?

Comment: I've added the css code including removal of the underline for on hover.
If it STILL does not work, I would suggest that you right-click on the link and choose Inspect Element. On the right-hand side under element.style, click and type text-decoration:none. If that works (and it will) check your CSS carefully.